# Power set of cartesian product where is {∅}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

X = {∅} × {{~}, *} = {(∅, {~}), (∅, *)}

P(X) = {∅, {(∅, {~})}, {(∅, *)}, {(∅, {~}), (∅, *)}}

is that correct?

Comment: I feel like your hesitance comes from the unusual symbols appearing.  Would you feel more comfortable if the question were instead asking about $X'=\{a\}\times\{b,c\}$ and finding $\mathcal{P}(X')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $X$ consists of $n=2$ elements. Call them $a$ and $b$. The power set ${\cal P}(X)$ then consists of $2^n=4$ elements, namely
$${\cal P}(X)=\bigl\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\bigr\}\ .$$
That's exactly what you have written.

Comment: I remember this property from my university days. I have given a positive vote.